# In Java, is `synchronized` equivalent to `synchronized (this)`?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I was looking through the source code for `DatagramSocket` and I found this:

```
public void disconnect() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (isClosed())
            return;
        if (connectState == ST_CONNECTED) {
            impl.disconnect ();
        }
        connectedAddress = null;
        connectedPort = -1;
        connectState = ST_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }
}
```

My understanding of [synchronized methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) is that they lock on `this`. So is the code equivalent to the following?

```
public synchronized void disconnect() {
    if (isClosed())
        return;
    if (connectState == ST_CONNECTED) {
        impl.disconnect ();
    }
    connectedAddress = null;
    connectedPort = -1;
    connectState = ST_NOT_CONNECTED;
}
```

Is there a reason why the language designers chose not to use a synchronized method here?

Comment: To provide a more precise answer to the title question: Using the `synchronized` specifier on a method is equivalent to `synchronized(this)` around the whole method body only for *non-static* methods. For *static* methods it is equivalent to `synchronized(NameOfYourClass.class)` around the whole method body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the two code snippets are equivalent.

We can only guess why whoever wrote this code chose the more verbose version. It could be someone's personal preference, or a historical artefact. For example, it might have previously been `synchronized(someObject)` or might have only covered part of the method, and whoever refactored the method didn't convert the `synchronized` section into a `synchronized` method.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reason why the language designers chose not to use a synchronized method here?

I don't know *their* minds, but in my mind, the first way is better.  I really dislike the phrase "synchronized method", because methods are not what we need to protect with synchronization.

We need to protect *data*.

The entire point of `synchronized` blocks, is that often, in order to advance the state of the program, one thread must create a temporary, *invalid* state.  With appropriate use of `synchronized` we can prevent any other thread from seeing the invalid state.  It means synchronizing not just the block of code that is changing the state, but also, any other block of code that can *examine* the state.

---

I believe that the idea for synchronized *methods* came from a paper published in the 1970s describing *monitors*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29 A monitor basically is an object whose methods are *all* atomic.  This was a useful abstraction when computer scientists were beginning to explore and formalize ways of *thinking* about parallel programming; but in a lot of practical applications, the "monitor" idea is too strict:  It's hard to make the most efficient use of a multiprocessor system using only monitors.